# Getting a tabbarcontroller after a navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a view controller with a button and after clicking that button tabbarcontroller should appear.how to do it programatically.?

all the tutorials i found show tab bar immediately once the app is started.but i want it to be visible after the button is clicked and navigated to the other view.

i wrote code for navigating to a new page so that new page should consist of tab bar controller.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked
{

 ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"view" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        [viewController release];
}
```

Comment: present the view controller modally, dismiss it when user taps the button

Comment: Actually Once my app is started splash screen appears and then after two navigations tabbar controller should appear.

Comment: either do what Vince suggests or write custom Tabbar Implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC1" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarItem *tbi1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"VC1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vc1"] tag:1];
    vc1.tabBarItem = tbi1;
    // more viewControllers here

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start of with a 'single empty view' project.
Then just add a new `UITabBarController` (out the top of my head)

```objc
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
[tbc.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, nil]];
[self.view addSubview:tbv.view];
```

Then you have to set the title and icon in the corresponding viewControllers in the `tabBarItem` property: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarItem